What is the relevance of mention of women in Jesus' Genealogy?
We have in Matthew 1 the Genealogy of Jesus. Though Israel followed a patriarchal lineage, the names of five women find a place in the Genealogy. They are: Tamar, Rahab, Ruth, Bathsheba, and Mary. Of course, Mary, being the Blessed Virgin Mother of Jesus, is an indispensable figure in the Genealogy. But, what is the relevance of the mentions of the other four women? Is the significance the result of a common attribute, or is it specific to each?

They are all non-Jewish.  (Not of Judah.) Tamar a Canaanite (presumably, for Shuah definitely was and Tamar's father is unnamed) ; Rahab, of Jericho, a Canaanite ; Ruth, the Moabitess ; and Uriah, a Hittite. (Note, the name of the wife of Uriah is not mentioned in the genealogy.) Mary was a close relative of Elizabeth and Elizabeth was of the daughters of Aaron, therefore a Levite, and Elizabeth was married to a Levite priest. Thus Mary was also of Levi, not of Judah.

Jesus was of the seed of David (Judah).  Not Levi.  John 7:42, Romans 1:3, 2 Tim 2:8.  Thus Mary was of Judah, not Levi.

@SLM 'of seed of David' is two of your quotes. 'Of the seed of David' is the other one. The seed of David, specifically, is Solomon. Or, it is generic, applying to 'seed' as the entire lineage. But in any case, both genealogies chart Joseph and his ancestry (not Mary's). But we know that Joseph was not the father. So, 'of' is origin in the sense of the right to the throne of David. But the curse (in Conia, noted by Jeremiah) prevents anyone of the physical seed of David obtaining the throne. Thus 'of' is lineage and ancestry through Joseph not Mary. 'Of' is not physical.

@NigelJ - If what you say were true there would be no evidence of the fulfilment of 2 Samuel 7:12-13, where our Lord is prophesied, to be out of the bowels of David, a biological descendant.  Luke shows Mary's father Heli is from David.  Mary was also from Aaron via Phinehas of Eleazar fulfilling Numbers 25:13.

@AndrewShanks The genealogy in Luke is Joseph's genealogy. And Jesus himself began to be about thirty years of age, being (as was supposed) the son of Joseph, which was of Heli, 2  Luke 3:23. Joseph is 'of Heli'. Mary is not mentioned. 2 Samuel 7:12-13 is about Solomon.

@NigelJ - 2 Sam 7:12-13 is about both Solomon & our Lord Christ. In Luke 3:23 the brackets are added for meaning. I believe the brackets are in wrong place and the meaning is "being (as was supposed the Son of Joseph) of Heli".. ie Jesus was the descendant of Heli, Mary's father, the nearest to a biological father of our Lord.  Matthew's Gospel shows our Lord's right to the throne as King of the Jews/Israel; Luke shows descent from Adam as Saviour of the World. Mary is not mentioned by name because of Jewish convention in their genealogies.

@NigelJ The generic term is not "seed", but "relative" that means kinsman, not blood cousin of some sort.  The seed of David understanding via Mary traces far further back in time then the apostolic time and support of Bible's John, Paul and Peter.  Gen 3:15 and then Rev 12:17.  Christ was of the seed of David, of Judah, not the erroneous idea of Levi.  Heb 7:11-17.

I could only find one of my commentaries on the gospel of Matthew that actually mentioned the point raised in this question. Here is what is said, with additions by myself about the four women in question.

"The main purpose of the genealogy is probably less to prove Jesus'
legal claim to the Davidic throne, and more to show that he was not
merely a revealer of divine truth but far more the climax of a
divinely guided historical process. The mention of the four women (3,
5, 6), all of them unattractive by orthodox Jewish standards, will
have been to counter discreditable rumours about Jesus' birth
circulating in Jewish circles." The International Bible Commentary,
p.1122 article on Matthew by H.L. Ellison, Marshall, Pickering,
Zondervan, 1986

Rumours about Jesus' birth included accusations that he was illegitimate (see John 8:41). However, widowed Tamar tricked her father-in-law Judah into fathering twin boys, Perez becoming the head of the leading clan in Judah, and the ancestor of David (see Ruth 4:18-22). Rahab had been a prostitute, yet accepted into the nation of Israel because of her faith. She was grandmother to Boaz who married Ruth.  Ruth was a Moabitess but became accepted into the nation of Israel as she forsook her pagan gods to become a woman of faith. Bathsheba was unlawfully taken by king David but birthed Solomon.
Therefore, anyone sneering at the son of the virgin Mary, supposing him to be illegitimate, was not only wrong about that, but didn't have a leg to stand on when it came to the genealogy of kings David and Solomon.

Thanks,  Anne . I sincerely doubt if anyone questioned the legitimacy of Jesus' birth. Joseph and Mary were legally wedded, and Jesus was seen as their son. What the Jews do in Jn 8:41 is to defend their claim that they are children of Abraham . They do not say that Jesus is not !

@KadalikattJosephSibichan The accusation was two-fold. 1. Thou art a Samaritan. (Thus illegitimate and adopted). 2. Hast a demon. The parents were espoused and then wedded. Of that, there was no accusation. On the basis 'thou art a Samaritan (and illegitimate) but we are not born of fornication, rests their argument.

Thanks, Nigel J. To my limited knowledge, Samaritans were a mixed breed of Jews and Gentiles. Jesus gives them a good position through the Parable of Good Samaritan. One doubts if the legality of their interfaith marriage was questioned thereby treating their offspring as illegitimate. In Jn 8:41, the Jews as only defending their ancestry, and not questioning that of Jesus. He was treated as son of Joseph, the carpenter , without even mentioning Mary's name !

I thought Christians believed Jesus was the Son of their God, and not of Joseph so doesn't that make the child illegitimate as far as the worldly laws are concerned? I realize that the divinity makes such issues irrelevant, but if someone accepts that Jesus was not the son of Joseph but in fact the Son of God, then that seems to also mean that He was an illegitimate child inasmuch as that carries any weight.

@terdon Joseph was the adoptive father of Mary's son because he never fathered Jesus. But nobody back then would even suppose adoption was in the mix because Joseph had married Mary before Jesus was born. So there was no actual, legal adoption required as everybody apart from a few people in the know took Joseph to be the physical father. He was not, but when those who hated Jesus wanted to find something to accuse him of, they cast the slur of being a Samaritan, whom they hated almost as much as they hated Jesus, viewing them as illegitimate re. national descent.

Well- explained, Anne.

There is a lot of evidence that Matthew wrote his gospel originally in Hebrew:

Originally Written in Hebrew. External evidence to the effect that
Matthew originally wrote this Gospel in Hebrew reaches as far back as
Papias of Hierapolis, of the second century C.E. Eusebius quoted
Papias as stating: “Matthew collected the oracles in the Hebrew
language.” (The Ecclesiastical History, III, XXXIX, 16) Early in the
third century, Origen made reference to Matthew’s account and, in
discussing the four Gospels, is quoted by Eusebius as saying that the
“first was written . . . according to Matthew, who was once a
tax-collector but afterwards an apostle of Jesus Christ, . . . in the
Hebrew language.” (The Ecclesiastical History, VI, XXV, 3-6) The
scholar Jerome (of the fourth and fifth centuries C.E.) wrote in his
work De viris inlustribus (Concerning Illustrious Men), chapter III,
that Matthew “composed a Gospel of Christ in Judaea in the Hebrew
language and characters for the benefit of those of the circumcision
who had believed. . . . Moreover, the Hebrew itself is preserved to
this day in the library at Caesarea, which the martyr Pamphilus so
diligently collected.”​—Translation from the Latin text edited by E.
C. Richardson and published in the series “Texte und Untersuchungen
zur Geschichte der altchristlichen Literatur,” Leipzig, 1896, Vol. 14,
pp. 8, 9.
Insight on the Scriptures - Volume 2

As such, it is not far-fetched to state that Matthew’s account of Jesus’ life was written primarily with the Jews in mind, to demonstrate to them that Jesus is the foretold Messianic King.
The women listed in Matthew’s genealogy of the Messiah are likely included in an otherwise all-male genealogy because there is something outstanding in the way each one came to be an ancestress of Jesus. Each of these women's history was well known by the common Jewish people.
Each displayed valuable qualities in the eyes of God. Tamar for her persistence and "righteousness" (Genesis 38:26), Rahab for her faith (Hebrews 11:30,31), Ruth for her loyal love and humility, Bathsheba for her loyalty and submission to her husband David even at old age and a non-ideal history with each other, and finally Mary who displayed all of the qualities above.
These women were proof, that God was at times using unusual paths (also in connection with women) to protect the genealogy towards the Messiah.

Well answered, Js Witness. But, what if Mtt was not written in Hebrew ? There are many who vote for Greek !

Matthew's story and narrative justify the Jesus-following Jews (and Gentiles) over and against nonbelieving Jews, highlighting the Jewish nature of Jesus's teaching and ministry even while incorporating the language of division and judgment against those who reject him (e.g., 23:1–39, 27:24–25). So whether he wrote his gospel originally in Hebrew and later translated it, or directly wrote it in koine Greek is of secondary relevance, as the story he tells has a lot of hints of being directed to Jewish Christians.
